# unneeded spaces in html div element

Tags: html, css

So I have this div I want to style to contain other divs listed one above the other but when I try to style one of the divs inside it adds some spacing before each one of those divs despite having both padding and margin at 0.

Here's the html and css:

```css
.result{
  width:40%;
  height:55%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0;
  /*display: none;*/
}
.res{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 25%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
<div class="res">
  <h4>something</h4>
  <span>something</span>
  <span>something</span>
</div>
<div class="res">
  <h4>something</h4>
  <span>something</span>
  <span>something</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you actually mean space _inside_, not before? That would be the effect of _collapsing/ adjoining margins_ (go read up on that), setting `margin-top` of the h4 to 0 will fix it.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of the spacing you see? There isn't any in your snippet.

Comment: @CBroe yeah i already fixed the problem, didn't know that h4 can cause such mess xD

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-child` to only apply CSS to first `div`. Or you can use `last-child` too.

```css
.result {
  width: 40%;
  height: 55%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0;
  /*display: none;*/
}

.result .res:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 25%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <div class="res">
    <h4>something</h4>
    <span>something</span>
    <span>something</span>
  </div>
  <div class="res">
    <h4>something</h4>
    <span>something</span>
    <span>something</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is the margin of the h4 i already found  the solution. thanks alot for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

you have problem in your logic

You see an unwanted space between `.res` containers (space before each of divs) space). right???

This is not space, You have applied `border-bottom: 2px solid #f4f4f4;`in your res container. Eliminate this line and it should be working as you expect. Here is the fiddle.

**Explanation:**
`border-bottom` feels like space in this case. So if we eliminate this, we get both containers feel like merged.

Comment: no what i meant is inside the .result div before each of the .res div there is a spacing, it's only noticeable when i added the hover. the problem with with the h4 margins and i already fixed but zeroing them out. thanks for the help.